# dataframe assembly from series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to make a new set of dataframes from another dataframe. I have a categorical feature image that is a column. For every image I want a df that now uses the images as the columns and has the rows

```
[image1]    [image1 cat]   [image2]     [image2 cat]    ...
(numerical  (categorical   (numerical   (categorical    ...
feature 1   feature        feature 1    feature         ...
values)     values)        values       values)         ...
```

After the assembly of each df I am then trying to write to an excel file (to share)

As it is now here is my code:

```
def excel_writer(df, split, file, store, drop): ##drop is just cols to ignore
    split_on = df[split].unique()
    print(split_on)
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in df.drop(columns = drop).columns:
        if (i != split) & (i not in store):
            print(i)
            df_tempo = df_temp.assign( split_on[0] = df[df[split] == split_on[0]][i])
            #print (df_temp)
            for q in store:
                df_temp[split_on[0] +' '+ q] = df[df[split] == split_on[0]][q]

            for j in split_on[1:]:
                print('\t',j)
                df_temp[j] = df[df[split] == j][i]
                for p in store:
                    df_temp[split_on[0] +' '+ q] = df[df[split] == split_on[0]][p]
        df_temp.to_excel("C:\\Users\\cf556\\Documents\\Stone 2018\\{}.xls".format(file), sheet_name=i)
```

df_temp.assign() does not work because it doesn't want me to use an expression (split_on[0]) as a keyword and df_temp[j] has an indexing problem as this is not its intended usage. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Behavior achieved using concat and Dataframe.reindex(). In retrospect .join() would probably also work.

code below:

```
def excel_writer(df, split, file, store, drop):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('{}.xlsx'.format(file))
    split_on = df[split].unique()
    print(split_on)
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame()


    for i in df.drop(columns = drop).columns:

        if (i != split) & (i not in store):
            # feature
            print(i)
            df_temp = pd.DataFrame()

            vals = df[df[split] == split_on[0]][i]
            vals.reset_index()

            df_temp =  pd.concat([df_temp, vals], axis=1)

            # naming
            df_temp.rename(columns={ df_temp.columns[-1]: split_on[0]}, inplace=True)



            for q in store:
                vals = df[df[split] == split_on[0]][q].reset_index()
                df_temp =  pd.concat([df_temp, vals], axis=1)
                df_temp.drop(columns = ['index'], inplace=True)

                df_temp.rename(columns={ df_temp.columns[-1]: split_on[0] +' '+ q }, inplace=True)

            for j in split_on[1:]:
                print('\t',j)
                vals = df[df[split] == j][i].reset_index()
                df_temp =  pd.concat([df_temp, vals], axis=1)
                df_temp.drop(columns =['index'], inplace=True)

                df_temp.rename(columns={ df_temp.columns[-1]: j }, inplace=True)

                for p in store:
                    #vals.rename(j +' '+ p) 
                    vals = df[df[split] == j][p].reset_index()
                    df_temp =  pd.concat([df_temp, vals], axis=1)
                    df_temp.drop(columns =['index'], inplace=True)
                    df_temp.rename(columns={ df_temp.columns[-1]: j +' '+ p }, inplace=True)
        print(df_temp.columns)
        df_temp.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=i)
        df_temp = df_temp.iloc[0:0]
    writer.close()

excel_writer(df_Eore, 'Image', 'tube_nuc', ['Type', 'Tom'], drop = ['Treatment', 'Animal', 'C.MassX', 'C.MassY', 'C.MassZ','Cat'])

print('done')
```